# What does this syntax ( page = $page ? $page : 'default' ) in PHP mean?

Tags: php, wordpress, ternary-operator, conditional-operator, language-construct

I'm new to PHP. I came across this syntax in [WordPress](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPress). What does the last line of that code do?

```
$page = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$page = str_replace("/","",$page);
$page = str_replace(".php","",$page);
$page = $page ? $page : 'default'
```

Comment: wow! overwhelming responses.. :) thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's an example of the conditional operator in PHP.

It's the shorthand version of:

```
if (something is true ) {
    Do this
}
else {
    Do that
}
```

See *[Using If/Else Ternary Operators](http://www.totallyphp.co.uk/tutorials/using_if_else_ternary_operators.htm)
http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php*.

Answer (score 7):

That's [the ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php):

That line translates to

```
if ($page)
    $page = $page;
else
    $page = 'default';
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the conditional operator". Don't you mean "the ternary operator" (one of the conditional operator***s***)?

Comment: I wrote "ternary operator" originally.  @Ether edited it and changed it to "conditional".  Curious.

Comment: "the ternary operator" is ambiguous because there can be more than one.

Comment: The docs seem to disagree: "Another conditional operator is the "?:" (or ternary) operator."

Answer (score 3):

It's a [ternary operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation) which is not PHP or WordPress specific, it exists in most langauges.

```
(condition) ? true_case : false_case
```

So in this case the value of $page will be "default", when $page is something similar to false — otherwise it will remain unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

It means that if $page does not have a value (or it is zero), set it to 'default'.

Answer (score 1):

More verbose syntax of the last line is:

```
if ($page)
{
    $page = $page;
}
else
{
    $page = 'default';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It means if the $page variable is not empty then assign the $page variable on the last line that variable or set it to 'default' page name.

[It is called conditional operator](http://www.tech-evangelist.com/2007/11/11/php-ternary-operator/)

Comment: It's misnamed **the** ternary operator where it really is just **a** ternary operater. Granted that in most language it is the only ternary operator implemented but that doesn't preclude the creation of other operators that takes 3 arguments. A language could for example have an operator for declaring functions, much like Forth's `:` operator, that operates on function name, parameter list and code block. That would also be a ternary operator.

Comment: "Conditional operator"? Don't you mean "ternary operator"?

Answer (score 0):

That's the so-called [conditional operator](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary). It functions like an if-else statement,
so

```
$page = $page ? $page : 'default';
```

does the same as

```
if($page)
{
    $page = $page;
}
else
{
    $page = 'default';
}
```

Comment: The reference says it is the ternary operator (or a ternary operator?), one of the conditional operators. Can you elaborate?