# What is ?: in PHP 5.3?

Tags: php, php-5.3, ternary-operator, conditional-operator, language-construct

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the PHP operators “?” and “:” called and what do they do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080247)

From http://twitto.org/

```
<?PHP
    require __DIR__.'/c.php';
    if (!is_callable($c = @$_GET['c'] ?: function() { echo 'Woah!'; }))
        throw new Exception('Error');
    $c();
?>
```

Twitto uses several new features available as of PHP 5.3:

1. The **DIR** constant
2. The ?: operator
3. Anonymous functions

---

1. What does number 2 do with the **?:** in PHP 5.3?
2. Also, what do they mean by anonymous functions? Wasn't that something that has existed for a while?

Comment: Has been answered at least twice http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080247/what-is-the-php-operator-called-and-what-does-it-do and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099834/what-does-this-syntax-in-php-mean

Comment: @gordon, I know what that means on those topics, I thought this was something different because the site said it was NEW as of 5.3 and also I never seen them together like "?:"

Comment: @Gordon those are only the longer forms. @jasondavis, you have the : and ? backwards in the question title.

Comment: ah okay. The *new* thing is that you can omit the middle part. And anonymous functions (lambda and closures) are a new addition to 5.3 as well, although you could create functions with `create_function` before.

Comment: this is not a duplicate.

Comment: It is not a duplicate for the considered question. This question is meant by PHP 5.3

Comment: Yes, please, guys with big enough hats, undo the hastened, mistaken "duplicate" flag! The linked other question is about the generic ternary, *with old, basic answers*, while this is about the the shorthand (which is, in fact, more than just syntactic sugar!). Following that wrong lead (trying to find out a subtlety, in vain) has resulted me wasting too many minutes from my life. Multiply that by the number of people harmed the same way, and it may even become a criminal category. ;)

Answer (score 145, accepted):

`?:` is a form of the conditional operator which was previously available only as:

```
expr ? val_if_true : val_if_false
```

In 5.3 it's possible to leave out the middle part, e.g. `expr ?: val_if_false` which is equivalent to:

```
expr ? expr : val_if_false
```

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php):

> Since PHP 5.3, it is possible to leave out the middle part of the conditional operator. Expression `expr1 ?: expr3` returns `expr1` if `expr1` evaluates to `TRUE`, and `expr3` otherwise.

Comment: Thank you!  I was confused when I saw them together like that "?:" and I searched but couldn't find anything on it.

Comment: Hmm very cool. That makes `?:` equivalent to `||` in Javascript!

Comment: As an added bonus, you can "chain" them: $foo = $bar ?: $bazz ?: $yadda ?: $qux; // $foo will be assigned the value of the first truthy variable. Not sure if this is a terrible idea (some dislike nesting ternary operators), but there it is.

Comment: @MSpreij I would say that is a concise usage of it. Normally, nesting ternary operators is terrible, yes (I would forgive up to one nested layer in some cases). The alternative to the above would be a very long and ugly if/elseif/else block that is just a waste really. As long as there is a comment such as the one you put for inexperienced programmers, then I would find this chaining perfectly acceptable (and actually I'm excited to use it, thanks for pointing it out!).

Comment: @MSpreij Actually, to further prove it isn't a terrible idea, PHP 7 introduced the [null coalescing operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) (I forgot about this myself) which does a similar thing and has the same general syntax - the difference being `isset()` vs truthy value though.

Answer (score 36):

The `?:` operator is the [conditional operator](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) (often refered to as the ternary operator):

> The expression `(expr1) ? (expr2) : (expr3)` evaluates to `expr2` if `expr1` evaluates to *TRUE*, and `expr3` if `expr1` evaluates to *FALSE*.

In the case of:

```
expr1 ?: expr2
```

The expression evaluates to the value of `expr1` if `expr1` is *true* and `expr2` otherwise:

> Since PHP 5.3, it is possible to leave out the middle part of the ternary operator. Expression `expr1 ?: expr3` returns `expr1` if `expr1` evaluates to *TRUE*, and `expr3` otherwise.

Answer (score 5):

[Look here:](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

> Since PHP 5.3, it is possible to leave out the middle part of the ternary operator. Expression expr1 ?: expr3 returns expr1 if expr1  evaluates to TRUE, and expr3 otherwise.

*Anonymous functions:* No, they didn't exist [before 5.3.0](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) (see the first note below the examples), at least in this way:

```
function ($arg) { /* func body */ }
```

The only way was `create_function()`, which is slower, quite cumbersome and error prone (because of using strings for function definitions).