# Clever way to do for loop () ? PHP

Tags: php, for-loop

I am looking to see if there is a smart or optimal way to try and do this for loop which so far I cannot get it to work.

I am trying to do it this way to stop me repeating code however if its not possible then I will just have to repeat code.

Here is what I tried

```
if(!isset($staff_rows)
for ($i=0; $i < 5; $i++)
else
for ($i=0; $i < $staff_rows; $i++)
```

So basically I want my forloop to use a variable $staff_rows if it is set otherwise just use default value of 5.

This is the error message

> Parse error : syntax error, unexpected T_FOR in

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: You'd missing a ). It should read if ( !isset($staff_rows) )

Comment: Why is everyone negging this - it is a completely legit question

Comment: That thing is called variable because you can change its value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the simplest way.

```
        $staff_rows = 5;

        // your code to change staff_rows 

        for ($i=0; $i <  $staff_rows; $i++) {
          // do something
        }
```

Comment: This one I have selected as the answer as it is simple in logic and is elegant!

Answer (score 4):

```
$min = (isset($staff_rows)) ? $staff_rows : 5 ;
for ($i=0; $i < $min; $i++) {
  //loop logic
}
```

Comment: why would that error? ofcourse you have to start { and loop logic later...

Comment: You're not comparing `$i` in your `for()` condition. You're merely defining and incrementing.

Answer (score 1):

```
for($i=0,$s=(isset($staff_rows)?$staff_rows:5);$i<$s;++$i) //do
```

**Added:**
More about ternary operator:
[What is ?: in PHP 5.3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153180/what-is-in-php-5-3)

Some benchmark.Manual page in gion_13's answer

```
$array=range(1,1000000);
$i=17;

$start= microtime(true);
$s=sizeof($array);
for($i=0;$i<$s;++$i){
;
}
print microtime(true)-$start;
print chr(10);



$start= microtime(true);
for($i=0,$s=sizeof($array);$i<$s;++$i){
;
}
print microtime(true)-$start;
print chr(10);

$start= microtime(true);
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($array);++$i){
;
}
print microtime(true)-$start;
print chr(10);
```

Output

```
0.18430280685425
0.1843409538269
1.3922038078308
```

Comment: Thanks what is the min() function? Does that select the most avaiable value?

Comment: @sqlmole, I get some mistake. You neednot min() here

Comment: @AlienWebguy, it is not in condition. It will calculate 1 time.

Comment: @Alien: This is good code. This calculation is computed only once. It's a know blindspot of many php developer. You should read better books or met a good CS teacher! P.S. It's not in the condition.

Comment: @Alien haha, "for ($i=0; $i<sizeOf($x); $i++)" and "for ($i=0,$s=sizeof($x); $i<$s; $i++)" is not same

Comment: first code calc sizeof() on every iteration, but second only once, before loop, when $i=0 does

Comment: Nuts, no. Blind, apparently. Commas appearing as semicolons... this is what happens when I code before breakfast! Thanks~

Comment: +1 for a solid benchmark

Comment: Thanks for hijacking my question - this function is not elegant and would be hard to read if maintenance was required on a system later on but thankyou :)

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite your code to be the following:

```
$limit = 5;
if (isset($staff_rows)) {
    $limit = $staff_rows;
}
for ($i=0; $i < $limit; $i++) { }
```

Your code will also be clearer with braces. Also you were missing a closing parentheses in the code sample that was in your question.

Comment: Yes but that will mean I will repeat code as I have to put all my echos in both for loops inside their braces.

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question at all.

Comment: @sqlmole If the code is identical within the respective loops, move it to a function.

Comment: @AlienWebguy It does now

Comment: I cannot have functions inside my View. I am using Codeigniter Frameworks which is MVC!! NO FUNCTIONS ALLOWED INSIDE A VIEW

Comment: @sqlmole Well, you didn't mention that restriction.

Comment: Well, you should have been psychic!

Comment: @sqlmole - hold on, I got a solution for you in that case

Answer (score 0):

besides the fact that you have a missing ")", you can do a single for loop:

```
for($i=0,$l=isset($staff_rows)?$staff_rows:5;$i<$l;$i++){
    // do your thing
}
```

it is efficient because you use only one `for`-loop.
The fact that I used logic(`$l=isset($staff_rows)?$staff_rows:5;`) in my loop does not affect its execution... but don't take my word for it :
From the [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) docs :

```
for (expr1; expr2; expr3)
    statement
```

> "The first expression (expr1) is evaluated (executed) **once** unconditionally at the beginning of the loop."

Comment: @Alien if you can't understand this code, it'snot means that code is bad

Comment: @Matt: Please think about what you writing first. This site is sh1t.

Comment: I have not selected this function although it is clever - (a) because it does not seperate the logic of two seperate functions easily and is (b) would be very hard to debug this is there was errors in value etc