# The use of "?" and ":"

Tags: php, javascript, asp.net

I've read through a lot of code where they have if statements, i've noticed other languages use this to. Asp being one.
Tried googling but couldn't find a answer for it.

What exactly does `?:` stand for and when to use it.

As far as I'm aware `?` is equal to `if()` and `:` being equal to `}else{`.

Comment: Is it `?:` your are looking for, or `bool ? true : false`. Because `?:` would lead to something like `value1 ?: value2` using `value1` if it evaluates to true.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is ?: in PHP 5.3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153180/what-is-in-php-5-3)

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation).

It is meant to simplify code in some cases. Consider this:

```
var str;

if(some_condition)
  str = 'yes';
else
  str = 'no';
```

This can be easily rewritten as

```
var str = some_condition ? 'yes' : 'no';
```

Comment: +1 Although, I'd say it's more syntactic sugar, the logic is the same.

Comment: @Peter: here - yes. In general - not the same.

Comment: What I meant by "logic is the same" is that it doesn't simplify anything.

Comment: As @OliCharlesworth correctly points out, `if/else` and ternary operator have different semantics. `if/else` is a control flow structure, ternary operator is an expression.

Comment: @Peter: code is shorter and easier to read. To me this looks like simplification :)

Comment: I know, we're just misunderstanding each other over semantics :)

Answer (score 7):

It is the [**ternary operator**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) (although in most languages it is better-named as the "conditional operator").

People will often erroneously refer to it as "shorthand if/else".  But this is a misnomer; `if/else` is a statement, `?:` is an expression.  In most languages, these are distinct concepts, with different semantics.

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is right.

It is a [Ternary operation (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation)

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, the syntax is `condition ? then-expession : else-expression`. Typically it is used in assigning variables:

```
varname = something == 123 ? "yes" : "no";
```

But it can be used pretty much anywhere in place of a value. It's mostly useful for avoiding repetitive code:

```
if( something == 123) {
    varname = "yes";
}
else {
    varname = "no";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java, it's an if/else relationship.

An example of a ternary operation:

```
boolean bool = (x==1) ? true : false;
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation

Comment: That's a pretty bad example, as it could be replaced with `(x==1)`.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a bad example, it's a redundant piece of code. It was used an an example, not as best software practice.

Comment: Actually, it's currently a syntax error (in most programming languages...)

Comment: better? :-)

    private static boolean getBoolean(int x) {
        return (x==1) ? true : false;
    }

Answer (score 0):

You could read the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).  The section you're looking for is titled "Ternary Operator".

Answer (score 0):

You can express calculations that might otherwise require an if-else construction more concisely by using the conditional operator. For example, the following code uses first an if statement and then a conditional operator to check for a possible division-by-zero error before calculating the sin function.

```
    if(x != 0.0) s = Math.Sin(x)/x; else s = 1.0;
    s = x != 0.0 ? Math.Sin(x)/x : 1.0;
```

from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28(v=vs.90).aspx