# Just need to understand a PHP Syntax used to set POSTed var

Tags: php, post

So I'm using the following php code to set variables that are received from a POST method, but I'm interested in how it works.

```
$var1 = isset($_REQUEST['var1']) ? $_REQUEST['var1'] : 'default';
```

I understand what it does, but I don't understand the syntax.

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: `$_REQUEST('var1')` should be `$_REQUEST['var1']`, shouldn't it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is ?: in PHP 5.3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153180/what-is-in-php-5-3) and [many others](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php). Please use the PHP tag wiki before asking questions about symbols in PHP.

Comment: Actually what you are typing is not setting a variable from $_POST, but from a requested variable on the site. $_REQUEST is just checking if the variable is from $_GET or $_POST as mentioned above.

But what you do is wrong, because if there is a $_GET variable set with the same name, it will get you the $_GET variable instead. Use pure $_POST for that.

Comment: @deceze and Panagiotis yes you're both right because $_REQUEST is an associative **array** that by default contains the contents of $_GET, $_POST and $_COOKIE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a short hand IF statement and from that you are assigning a value to $var1

The syntax is :

```
$var = (CONDITION) ? (VALUE IF TRUE) : (VALUE IF FALSE);
```

Answer (score 5):

? is just a short and optimised notation of doing this:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST["var1"])) // If the element "var1" exists in the $_REQUEST array
   $var1 = $_REQUEST["var1"]; // take the value of it
else
   $var1 = "default"; // if it doesn't exist, use a default value
```

Note that you might want to use the $_POST array instead of the $_REQUEST array.

Comment: Thanks for the answer... I'd vote it up but I don't have enough reputation points :)

Answer (score 3):

You probably mean [ternary operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

Syntax it's same like

```
if(isset($_REQUEST('var1') ) {
    $var1 = ? $_REQUEST('var1')
}else {
    $var1 =: 'default';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's the synatx of the ternary operator. It's shorthand for if/else. Please read [PHP Manaul](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

Answer (score 0):

This is a 'ternary operator', what it says is:-

If var1 is set as a post variable then set var1 to that value, otherwise setvar1 to be the string 'default'.  Using traditional syntax it would be:-

```
if (isset($_REQUEST('var1')) { $var1 = $_REQUEST('var1'); } else { $var1 = 'default'; }
```

Answer (score -1):

its a short way of doing an if. if you are expecting a post variable its must better to use _POST rather than request.

the "?" says if the isset($_REQUEST) is true, then do the everything between the ? and : otherwise do everything between the : and the ;