# PHP code meaning and usage

Tags: php

What does this piece of PHP actually mean and how could it be displayed differently?

```
'S_DISPLAY_VEHICLE_OWNER'   => ($owned == 'MODERATE' || $owned == 'YES') ? 1 : 0
```

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2153180/1935077

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
'S_DISPLAY_VEHICLE_OWNER'   => ($owned == 'MODERATE' || $owned == 'YES') ? 1 : 0
```

another look:

```
if ($owned == 'MODERATE' || $owned == 'YES'){
 $result = 1;
}else{
 $result = 0;
}

'S_DISPLAY_VEHICLE_OWNER'   => $result
```

Answer (score 2):

It sets `S_DISPLAY_VEHICLE_OWNER` with a shorthand notation of if/else.

```
if($owned == 'MODERATE' OR $owned == 'YES') {

    return 1

}else{

    return 0

}
```

Answer (score 0):

if $owned equals 'MODERATE' or 'YES' then the `S_DISPLAY_VEHICLE_OWNER` variable will be populated with 1 else 0

Answer (score 0):

Basically in plaintext the expression `($owned == 'MODERATE' || $owned == 'YES') ? 1 : 0` means

```
if owned is moderate or owned is yes then 1 else 0
```

The field `S_DISPLAY_VEHICLE_OWNER` in your array is set to `1` or `0` depending on 
the value of $owned.

Answer (score 0):

It's assigning a value of 1 or 0 to an associative array if the value of `$owned` is either "MODERATE" or "YES." So, if the array were `$arr`, then it could be rewritten as:

```
if ($owned == 'MODERATE' || $owned == 'YES'){
   $arr['S_DISPLAY_VEHICLE_OWNER'] = 1;
} else {
   $arr['S_DISPLAY_VEHICLE_OWNER'] = 0;
}
```