# Sort an array of integers according to frequency of elements. If the frequency of two elements are same then they will be printed in ascending order

Tags: php, algorithm, sorting

**For example**, input array is [9,1,9,1,3,9,1,2,9] output array will be [9,9,9,9,1,1,1,2,3].

Here's what I've tried below but not giving me expected result:

```
$array = [9,1,9,1,3,9,1,2,9];
$values = array_count_values($array);
arsort($values);
$popular = array_keys($values);

print_r(array_values($popular));

foreach ($values as $key => $val) {
    echo $key.", ";
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 9
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 2
)
9, 1, 3, 2,
```

Comment: I have tried using "array_count_values()" function in php but the problem is it prints only one case of the repeated element, I want all elements to print in order of frequency. Thanks in advance guys...

Comment: Please visit [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to learn how to create a minimal, reproducible question. You should not be explaining the whole question in header and you should show what you have tried so far.

Comment: @DjSh Thanks for your response.. I've tried it severally but no way out yet... Please help out if you can.. Thanks

Comment: we need to see your code

Comment: Check, I have updated with my code.. thank you

Comment: Any idea yet please..?

Answer (score 1):

If we loop the array_count_values then we can make sure they come in the correct order.
When there is two that is the same count I find all the same with array_intersect then foreach them and add in the correct order.

```
$array = [9,1,9,1,3,9,1,2,9];
$values = array_count_values($array);
arsort($values);
//var_dump($values);

$result =[];
$same = [];
foreach($values as $key => $val){
    if(!in_array($key, array_keys($same))){
        if(next($values) != $val){
            $result = array_merge($result, array_fill(0, $val, $key));
        }else{
            $same = array_intersect($values, [$val]);
            ksort($same);
            foreach($same as $skey => $val){
                $result = array_merge($result, array_fill(0, $val, $skey));
            }
            //var_dump($same);
        }
    }
}

var_dump($result);
```

https://3v4l.org/sk44Q

Answer (score 0):

Try [usort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) combined with array_count (php >= 7.0):

```
$array = [9,1,9,1,3,9,1,2,9];

$arrayCounts = array_count_values($array);

usort($array, function ($a, $b) use ($arrayCounts) {
    $countA = $arrayCounts[$a] ?? 0;
    $countB = $arrayCounts[$b] ?? 0;
    if ($countA == $countB) {
       return $a == $b ? 0 : ($a < $b ? -1 : 1);
    }
    return ($countA > $countB) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Comment: Thanks marv255, it's still not working.. Have you tried it?

Comment: @InformalJoke [example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2bb3f00232de72ba591696d6ea99cd3168186368).

Comment: I think the 2 and 3 at the end are the wrong way round.

Comment: @InformalJoke. Yes forgot about asc. Update answer with fixed function and [fixed example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6808a3b9318aa2b5d180a0824e4cd76f32a8d6b6).

Comment: Wow, works like magic now... But I'm lost honestly, the code is complex... any explanation please. Thank you very very much... and I would love to connect with you and learn, twitter handle or any means ?... thanks again..

Answer (score 0):

You could use this sequence:

```
$arrayCounts = array_count_values($array);
usort($array, function ($a, $b) use ($arrayCounts) {
    return $arrayCounts[$b] - $arrayCounts[$a] ?: $a - $b; 
});
```

Now `$array` is sorted as requested.

The callback function that is passed as argument to `usort` should return a negative number when the two elements `$a` and `$b` should stay in that order (from left to right), or a positive number when they should be reversed. 0 when it does not matter.

The numeric expression that is returned in this particular callback function subtracts the frequencies of `$a` and `$b`. If `$b` occurs more, then that subtraction is positive, and that is returned. Similarly if the subtraction is negative, then that negative value is returned. Now when the frequencies are equal, the [`?:` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2153189/5459839) kicks in and the expression after it is evaluated. That other subtraction also results in a positive or negative value, based on the original value itself. So `$a - $b` will be negative when `$a < $b`, which means the order can remain as it is (knowing that we already derived that their frequencies were equal).

Comment: Wow.. working fine, but not in ascending order for same frequency element yet...

Thanks alot..

I think I need to learn this usort concept.. 

Thanks again...

Comment: I edited my answer. It seems to order ascending for same frequency.

Comment: Also added an explanation of what this callback function passed to `usort` is doing.

Comment: For PHP 7+, you could use the spaceship operator `<=>`.

Comment: @vivek_23, true, although I find that less useful for numeric data. A minus sign is two characters less than the spaceship ;-)

Comment: @trincot Haha, ok :) But it wouldn't make much computational difference and makes your code cleaner(although the reader needs to know about it beforehand).

Comment: @trincot Thanks alot sir, it works just fine now... Please is there a way I can connect with you, are you on twitter..?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You can just drop a comment in a comment box with my name, and I'll respond. My profile mentions a mail adres, but I don't monitor it daily.